# jquery fill inputfield automatically in calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a field for percentage where the user can type in a number and gets automatically the percentage value:

https://jsfiddle.net/km6Lznex/

(please consider to add 'event' as a parameter to the function in jsfiddle, in case of using firefox)

```
$('#table').on('keyup', '.update', function (event) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) return false;
    calculateTotals();
});

$('#percent').change(function () {
    calculateTotals();
});

function calculateTotals(){
    var dscnt_addition_percent = $('#percent');
    var dscnt = dscnt_addition_percent.val().trim().replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, ''); 
    dscnt = dscnt == '' ? 0 : dscnt;
    dscnt_addition_percent.val(dscnt);      

    var subtotal = parseInt($('#sum').val());
    var grandTotal = $('#grandTotal').val();
    var m = dscnt_addition_percent.val() * subtotal/100;
    $('#euro').val(m);
    $('#grandTotal').val(m + subtotal);
}

<div id="table">
  € <input type="text"  id="euro"  placeholder="0,00 €" /><br>
  % <input type="text"  id="percent" value="0" placeholder="0,00 %" /><br>
  subtotal <input type="text" class="update" id="sum" disabled value="10000" /><br>
  total  <input type="text" class="form-control update" id="grandTotal"  placeholder="0,00" />
```

Now I would like to do it with the textfield for €. When i type in a amount, the percentage-field and total-field should update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change `#percent` it calculates new value for `#grandTotal` and `#euro` taking input as `#sum` and `#percent`.Now you want same thing when changing `#euro`, taking itself and `#sum` as input.Since you are now calculating % you need to change the function a little bit 
ie.

when `#percent` is changed `euro = percent * subtotal/100;`

when `#euro` is changed  `percent = euro * 100/subtotal;`

so either you can use a separate function OR use the same with `even.target` which tells exactly which textbox is the origin of the event

```
function calculateTotals(event)
{
    var dscnt_addition_percent = $('#percent');
    ...
    ..
    .

    if(event.target.id=="percent")
    {
    //CALCULATE €
    }

    if(event.target.id=="euro")
    {
    //CALCULATE %
     var euro = $("#euro").val();
     var subtotal = parseInt($('#sum').val());

     var percent= euro * 100/subtotal;
     dscnt_addition_percent.val(percent);
     $('#grandTotal').val(euro + subtotal);
    }

}
```

Also little change here

```
$('#table').on('keyup', '.update', function (event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
  if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) return false;
  calculateTotals(event);
});

$('#percent,#euro').change(function (event) {
  calculateTotals(event);
});
```